# Annotating MKMapView in offline mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, android-mapview, offline

In my application, I have a map view displaying nearby locations in a regeon. I can annotate my current location and other fixed locations in the map when the application be in online. The User would change his location(he is travelling),and some time he would be in offline mode. Is there any way to display his current location in map in offline mode? I could display the all other fixed locations already pinned into map.

Comment: u can get the lat-long locations in the offline mode right? u have to just refresh ur map view or refresh user location pin..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to display pins in off line mode. When I added pin in on line and if the application goes off line, I can view the pins but when the map were refreshed, (like going to next view and coming back), I cant see the pins any more. I then used [CloudMade](http://cloudmade.com/) maps.